# Setting up main site while also using a wildcard subdomain - Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I currently have web application with wildcard subdomains pointed to it. I want to be able to also have an informational website that points to my app.

To clarify, right now we have demo-company.domain.com, as well as any other subdomain that is valid and will point to our app. But I also want to be able to use domain.com and www.domain.com to just host an informational website that points potential customers to the actual application.

So far I have tried by adding the www subdomain as a CNAME pointing to the static website, but it keeps pointing to the main application despite the fact that I have other CNAME records that do point correctly to it. We are using AWS Cloudfront for both the app and the website in case it is relevant in any way.

Has anyone else ever tackled this before?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to fix this in your webserver configuration.

Comment: Well, good luck with fixing DNS! (I did not downvote your post, but I will give you an upvote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by using an ALIAS A record to the specific Cloudfront I was using. For some reason a typical CNAME to it just didn't work as expected.